# Add a custom PHP function to MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I'm wondering what's the best way to extend the MAMP PHP core itself so that custom functions will be available globally without the need to import libraries.

A good example of what I want to do is to have a `dd` function (which is `var_dump()` + `die()`, inspired by Laravel) available in all my local projects.

These methods need to be available only on my local environement (where my version of MAMP is installed) and for debugging purposes only, so there is no fear of breaking PHP funcionality on end server.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches for this:

1. Adding a module to php which is loaded like all the other modules. Modules like database connectors, math libraries, translation functions, whatever. All those functions are *not* part of "the php core". The core implements only the language itself. You can see what modules are currently loaded and their configurations in your php setup by using the function `phpinfo()`. 
   Implementing a module is possible, you need to know c or c++ langauge for this. An interesting project, you will learn a lot. But this is also a huge overhead to what you are looking for.
2. Implement your functions in a normal php file somewhere outside your normal project folder. Then register that file inside your http servers php configuration as "to be loaded for every executed script". That is exactly what the "auto_prepend_file" feature does. That way you can easily add global functions always available in all scripts on your local system.

Believe me, you want to give the second approach a try :-)

Comment: I'll be definitely trying the 2nd approach first! Seems very straight forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without compiling your own extension to PHP, creating a global function that is automatically available to all scripts on the box without importing anything may be impossible.

You could create a file like "tools.php" that contains the `dd` function definition, and you do a call like `require "tools.php"` in your application. Put the development version of `tools.php` in a directory that is only available on the development server, in a path that is given highest priority in the include_path.

Then create a mirror `tools.php` in the codebase, with a lower priority in the include_path, that contains only stubs to your development methods. Therefore, on the dev box, the dev version of tools.php will be included. But on production, the production version of tools.php would be included.

Comment: My additional comment to this is that, if you can, you should try to move away from debugging-by-print and instead look into setting up xdebug so you can inspect memory space and step through the functional flow of your application.

Comment: You should take a look at the "auto_prepend_file" feature available in most http servers supporting php. :-)

Comment: @arkascha that's a great idea, thank you! I could even use that to override some stuff on my dev php instance